# How to get all children of a particular type in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have written a method that works, but feels inelegant. I'm wondering if I've missed a better way.

I have a polymorphic association set up like so;

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phoneable, polymorphic: true
end
```

My phones table has standard `phoneable_id:integer` and `phoneable_type:string` columns.

What I want to do is get all of the phones for a previously selected group of employees, e.g.

```
employees = Employee.where role: 'peon'
```

If this was a normal `has_many` relationship I would then write my phones query as;

```
Phone.where employee_id: employees
```

To do this in a polymorphic relationship I have written my query as;

```
Phone.where phoneable_type: 'employee', phoneable_id: employees
```

This works, but I feel like there should be a better way of doing this than explicitly stating the `phoneable_type`. Does Rails have a way of doing this automagically when presented with a collection of employees, or am I over-reaching for simplicity?

Answer (score -1):

You did not understand the complete importance of polymorphic association. If you have defined it in your models, you can easily fetch the records as following:

Lets assume you have an 'Peon' role in your employee table:

```
@employee = Employee.where(role: 'peon').first
```

Now you can fetch records like this:

```
 @employee.phones
```

If you want to fetch all the phones for employees who have 'peon' role, you can do like this:

```
@employees = Employee.where(role: 'peon')   

@peon_phones = @employees.map{|x| x.phones}
```

Same in case of Client as well :

```
@client = Client.first

@client.phones
```

Its as simple as you imagine. Hope it will help.Thanks

Comment: Yes, except using map like that results in a huge number of database requests and is potentially very slow. I'm always looking for a database only solution.

Answer (score -1):

In order to accomplish this with a single query in Rails 5 (which has come out since this question), you could do:

```
Phone.where(phoneable: employees)
```

Rails will be able to infer the id and type from the objects in the `employees` collection.